# Unable to login to django admin on production

Tags: django, apache, django-admin

I am unable to login to my django admin site on an app that is on production on an apache2 server. When I run python manage.py runserver xx.xx.xx.xx:8000 (xx:xx:xx:xx is my remote IP) on the remote server, everything works fine and I'm able to login to the django admin site. On my local machine, I'm also able to login well. However when the site is served by apache on the remote server, I am unable to login to the admin site despite using valid credentials.
What could be the problem? I am not sure what setting(s) may be wrong so I don't know what code snippet to post!

Comment: in production, you are using different database? can you post the exact steps you did to deploy?

Comment: Nope, same DB and everything's synced. I actually get no error; just a redirect to the same login page.

Comment: Nope...but I'm sure I get authenticated because if I use wrong credentials I get an error.

Comment: did you hook into admin code somewhere?

Comment: what happens if you go to /admin after you get authenticated and redirected. again redirected?

Comment: Nope...as I said in my question, when I run the site using django's server, everything goes well.

Comment: then something is wrong with your apache config

Answer (score 0):

Clear your admin site cookies. Your production site cookie is probably mismatched with the production secret key, or you're using the same secret key which can also cause a mismatch.

Comment: And how can I clear the admin site cookies? Is it a problem if I use the same key on my dev and prod environments?

Comment: Easiest answer is to use Firebug in Firefox or Chrome Developer Tools or one of several plugins for both. Clearing cookies is always an early thing to try with issues like this. It does seem to be an issue if you have the same secret key for prod and dev although I couldn't tell you why exactly.